# DocumentID ignored in AnchorTab's in multiple document envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I found [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740366/docusign-with-multiple-documents-in-an-envelope-is-a-document-specific-anchorst) on this topic however noone has answered that post and I wasn't able to add my comments to it.

I am testing a multi-document / multi-signer scenario via the SOAP API.  I have 2 documents, each with 2 signer fields tagged with values recipient1Sign and recipient2Sign respectively.  I have specified AnchorTabStrings for the signer fields on my xml to correlate with the anchor tags on the forms (see sample xml below).  I'm finding that the Tab definition and it's associated DocumentID does not provide scoping for the AnchorTabString when DocuSign adds the signer tags to the form meaning that if different recipients on different doucuments use tabs that have AnchorTabStrings with the same value, both recipients see signer tabs on both documents.  In other words, the tab definition and its corresponding AnchorTabString definitions are not being considered unique within the envelope.  The [DocuSign documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Rules%20for%20Anchor%20Tagging.htm) pretty clearly states that the AnchorTabString definition is supposed to be scoped to a document (which is what I want), not scoped at the envelope level (which is what my testing is showing).

I've included excerpts of the recipeint and tab definitions being used in my testing below.

```
            <ns1:Recipients>

              <ns1:Recipient>

                <ns1:ID>1</ns1:ID>

                <ns1:UserName>John Doe</ns1:UserName>

                <ns1:SignerName>John Doe</ns1:SignerName>

                <ns1:Email>johndoe@abc.com</ns1:Email>

                <ns1:Type>Signer</ns1:Type>

                <ns1:RequireIDLookup>false</ns1:RequireIDLookup>

                <ns1:RoutingOrder>1</ns1:RoutingOrder>

              </ns1:Recipient>

              <ns1:Recipient>

                <ns1:ID>2</ns1:ID>

                <ns1:UserName>Jane Doe</ns1:UserName>

                <ns1:SignerName>Jane Doe</ns1:SignerName>

                <ns1:Email>janedoe@xyz.com</ns1:Email>

                <ns1:Type>Signer</ns1:Type>

                <ns1:RequireIDLookup>false</ns1:RequireIDLookup>

                <ns1:RoutingOrder>1</ns1:RoutingOrder>

              </ns1:Recipient>

              <ns1:Recipient>

                <ns1:ID>3</ns1:ID>

                <ns1:UserName>Jack Doe</ns1:UserName>

                <ns1:SignerName>Jack Doe</ns1:SignerName>

                <ns1:Email>jackdoe@xyz.com</ns1:Email>

                <ns1:Type>Signer</ns1:Type>

                <ns1:RequireIDLookup>false</ns1:RequireIDLookup>

                <ns1:RoutingOrder>1</ns1:RoutingOrder>

              </ns1:Recipient>

            </ns1:Recipients>
```

The example requires definition of 2 documents in the XML:

```
            <ns1:Documents>

              <ns1:Document>

                <ns1:ID>1</ns1:ID>

                <ns1:Name>Test Doc 1</ns1:Name>

                <ns1:PDFBytes>JVBERi0xLjcNJeLjz</ns1:PDFBytes>

                <ns1:TransformPdfFields>true</ns1:TransformPdfFiel​ds>

                <ns1:FileExtension>PDF</ns1:FileExtension>

              </ns1:Document>

              <ns1:Document>

                <ns1:ID>2</ns1:ID>

                <ns1:Name>Test Doc 2</ns1:Name>

                <ns1:PDFBytes>9MNCjExIDAgb2Jq</ns1:PDFBytes>

                <ns1:TransformPdfFields>true</ns1:TransformPdfFiel​ds>

                <ns1:FileExtension>PDF</ns1:FileExtension>

              </ns1:Document>

            </ns1:Documents>
```

The example requires definition of signer tabs in the xml:

```
              <ns1:Tab>

                <ns1:DocumentID>1</ns1:DocumentID>

                <ns1:RecipientID>1</ns1:RecipientID>

                <ns1:ScaleValue>50</ns1:ScaleValue>

                <ns1:AnchorTabItem>

                  <ns1:AnchorTabString>recipient1Sign</ns1:AnchorTabString>

                  <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPrese​nt>

                </ns1:AnchorTabItem>

                <ns1:Type>SignHere</ns1:Type>

                <ns1:TabLabel>Customer</ns1:TabLabel>

                <ns1:TemplateLocked>true</ns1:TemplateLocke​d>

                <ns1:TemplateRequired>false</ns1:TemplateRequired>

              </ns1:Tab>

              <ns1:Tab>

                <ns1:DocumentID>1</ns1:DocumentID>

                <ns1:RecipientID>2</ns1:RecipientID>

                <ns1:ScaleValue>50</ns1:ScaleValue>

                <ns1:AnchorTabItem>

                  <ns1:AnchorTabString>recipient2Sign</ns1:AnchorTabString>

                  <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPrese​nt>

                </ns1:AnchorTabItem>

                <ns1:Type>SignHere</ns1:Type>

                <ns1:TabLabel>Representative</ns1:TabLabel>

                <ns1:TemplateLocked>true</ns1:TemplateLocked>

                <ns1:TemplateRequired>false</ns1:TemplateRequired>

              </ns1:Tab>

              <ns1:Tab>

                <ns1:DocumentID>2</ns1:DocumentID>

                <ns1:RecipientID>1</ns1:RecipientID>

                <ns1:ScaleValue>50</ns1:ScaleValue>

                <ns1:AnchorTabItem>

                  <ns1:AnchorTabString>recipient1Sign</ns1:AnchorTabString>

                  <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPrese​nt>

                </ns1:AnchorTabItem>

                <ns1:Type>SignHere</ns1:Type>

                <ns1:TabLabel>Owner</ns1:TabLabel>

                <ns1:TemplateLocked>true</ns1:TemplateLocked>

                <ns1:TemplateRequired>false</ns1:TemplateRequired>

              </ns1:Tab>

              <ns1:Tab>

                <ns1:DocumentID>2</ns1:DocumentID>

                <ns1:RecipientID>3</ns1:RecipientID>

                <ns1:ScaleValue>50</ns1:ScaleValue>

                <ns1:AnchorTabItem>

                  <ns1:AnchorTabString>recipient2Sign</ns1:AnchorTabString>

                  <ns1:IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</ns1:IgnoreIfNotPrese​nt>

                </ns1:AnchorTabItem>

                <ns1:Type>SignHere</ns1:Type>

                <ns1:TabLabel>Payer</ns1:TabLabel>

                <ns1:TemplateLocked>true</ns1:TemplateLocked>

                <ns1:TemplateRequired>false</ns1:TemplateRequired>

              </ns1:Tab>

            </ns1:Tabs>
```

..

Comment: I've never seen DocumentID actually do anything in this situation either.  Ultimately we didn't need (or want) to limit by Document so I let it go despite not getting a direct answer on why it doesn't match documentation.  

Have you verified you require document specific anchors for your scenario?  I'm only asking because if you look at a role based approach it might become less likely.  For example if you have a "LoanApplicant" as one role it's unlikely you want that to vary between documents.  One person signs all their locations within the entire envelope. Same for "LoanOriginator", etc...

Comment: I have one use case where I think document level scoping could come into play:  Multiple instance of the same form where an employee signs on one field on that form and a financial rep signs on a second field on the form.  This use case used a 1 - 1 mapping of documents in the invitation to employee (i.e. 10 employees, 10 documents included in the invitation).  I suppose the workaround for this scenario is to send 10 separate invitations to sign (1 document in each invitation). This would be a lot of individual emails for the financial rep to have to process 1 x 1.

Comment: My initial impression of that scenario is it'd be better served as separate transactions.  But yes, the single financial rep may need special consideration to make sure their signing workflow is as smooth as possible.  Ex: maybe they go into the Web Console or Mobile app once a day and sign them all instead of clicking on each email as it comes in.

Comment: I have a bug report open with DocuSign support now and they are confirming whether this is a bug or a "feature".